# ssis - get data more xml files has defined as optional tag

Tags: xml, ssis, xsd

I have a xml file.I want to import data sql database.
File has two lines. Line 1 has not skf:OrderAcknowledgeReasonComponent tag but Line 2 has skf:OrderAcknowledgeReasonComponent tag.

I am using Xml Source. How can I do it?

```
<SalesOrder> 
<Header> </Header> 
<Line> 
   <LineNumber> 1 </LineNumber> 
   <NetUnitPrice>2 </NetUnitPrice> 
</Line> 
<Line> 
   <LineNumber> 2 </LineNumber> 
   <NetUnitPrice>3 </NetUnitPrice> 
   <skf:OrderAcknowledgeReasonComponent> Test </skf:OrderAcknowledgeReasonComponent> 
</Line> 
</SalesOrder>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwhwH.png)

Comment: <SalesOrder>
    <Header>
    </Header>
    <Line>
     <LineNumber> 1 </LineNumber>
      <NetUnitPrice>2 </NetUnitPrice>
    </Line>
    <Line>
    <LineNumber> 2 </LineNumber>
      <NetUnitPrice>3 </NetUnitPrice>
    <skf:OrderAcknowledgeReasonComponent>
    Test
    </skf:OrderAcknowledgeReasonComponent>
    </Line>
    </SalesOrder>

Answer (score 0):

SSIS XML Source Adapter is using XSD to define XML file structure and data types. You can edit that XSD file and make sure that the optional `<skf:OrderAcknowledgeReasonComponent>` element is there.